# Disallowed Host at Django

Tags: python, django

I'm just starting out with Django for the first time. So I create a django project and run the command

```
python3  manage.py  runserver  0.0.0.0:8000
```

Instead of getting the expected django homepage, I get the following error message,

```
DisallowedHost at /
Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '0.0.0.0:8000'. You may need to add '0.0.0.0' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://0.0.0.0:8000/
Django Version: 1.10.5
Exception Type: DisallowedHost
Exception Value:    
Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '0.0.0.0:8000'. You may need to add '0.0.0.0' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/http/request.py in get_host, line 113
Python Executable:  /usr/local/opt/python3/bin/python3.5
Python Version: 3.5.2
```

I haven't yet scratched the surface of django, so would appreciate some help as to how to fix this?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

literally as the error suggested! go ahead and add the line

`0.0.0.0` to the `ALLOWED_HOSTS` in your `settings.py`

The error info is quite explicit. It should solve the problem right away.

Comment: For those with a domain website add 'sitesname.com'

Comment: Just to make things even more explicit: change the line `ALLOWED_HOSTS = []` to `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['0.0.0.0']`

Comment: This answer solves this particular problem, but it is not great advice to just believe the error message and blindly add the IP address to the list of allowed hosts. Your server could be giving you this error because someone is trying to access your site via via a different host name.

Comment: "*" allows from all hosts!

Answer (score 8):

I too had problems with this and it is not easy for a beginner to fix.  Here below is the sequence required:

First find your settings.py file, which is located:

projectName/projectName/settings.py

You can also find it using:
 find -name "settings.py" 
- likely you will have only one!

Once you have found this, you need to open it in a text editor and change the line

ALLOWED_HOSTS =[ ] to ALLOWED_HOSTS =['your.host.ip.address'] - include the ' ' and the [ ]  then save.
You will have to re-start the server to get this to work eg:

```
   python manage.py runserver your.host.ip.address:8000
```

If you get a syntax error, make sure you have something that looks like:

`ALLOWED_HOSTS =['192.168.1.200']` or whatever your ip address is.

Answer (score 1):

1- run

ifconfig
  check you ip address, and you should add the ip to this lone:
ALLOWED_HOSTS =['you IP address goes here']

2- run:

python manage.py your-ip:8000

3- go to your browser and check you ip:8000

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just close the postman and try request in new tab. This worked for me.

Comment: This was it for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1.You can also find it using: find -name "SETTINGS.py" - likely you will have only one!

2.Once you have found this, you need to open it in a text editor and change the line in the insetting File

```
 ALLOWED_HOSTS =['Your_compte_pythonanywher.pythonanywhere.com']
```

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, you can have a file *local_settings.py* and *settings.py*.

If you are running in a local or a VPS server considered as local server:

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8001
```

You need to add in *local_settings.py*

Also you can search how many ALLOWED_HOSTS has your code with:

```
grep -rin ALLOWED_HOSTS your_source_path
```