# How to fix Django-admin SAVE button problem?

Tags: django-admin

When I save a new entry, I get this huge error, where the last line says `You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard page generated by the handler for this status code.`

When I do so, I get another error `CommandError: You must set settings.ALLOWED_HOSTS if DEBUG is False.`

I am following a tutorial to learn Django and I think I have done as explained in the tutorial

```
DEBUG = True
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'products.apps.ProductsConfig'
]
```

snippet of settings.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Product

# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(Product)
```

admin.py

```
from django.db import models


class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    price = models.FloatField() 
    stock = models.IntegerField()
    image_url = models.CharField(max_length=2083)

class Offer(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    discount = models.FloatField()
```

models.py

[This is where I give my entry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtC5E.png)

[This is when I click the save button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fa66A.png)

Answer (score 0):

You don't say which error the debug shows, however you'll want to read the debug and solve that error as well.

Meantime, since you've turned debug off, you still want your app to run, although it will still have the above error.

Django has to know the host that is running the app in the runserver, as a redirect protection mechanism. If ALLOWED_HOSTS is blank, it only assumes localhost, so would only work from a browser or proxy on the same server.

To enable runserver to work, set the IP address on your server in
(project directory)/settings.py
ALLOWED_HOSTS = [ '10.1.1.10', ]  # Use IP address of your host, not this example IP.

Since you've turned debug off, you'll need to restart your runserver
(venv)$ python manage.py runserver 0:8080

Your port number may be different.

Now you may be able to browse to your app from another system.

A similar question is also discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41755223/disallowed-host-at-django/41755231)